# Getting error ORA-00904: "ID_NAME_COLL_TYPE": invalid identifier while creating view with oracle object

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am reading book `Practical Oracle SQL`. In this book in chapter 2 Author is creating a view with User defined types. Here are the queries

```
create or replace type id_name_type as object (
    id     integer, 
   name   varchar2(20 char)
);
/

create or replace type id_name_coll_type as table of id_name_type;
/

create or replace view customer_order_products_obj
as
select
    customer_id, 
    max(customer_name) as customer_name, 
    cast(
        collect(
            id_name_type(product_id, product_name)
            order by product_id
        ) as id_name_coll_type
    ) as product_coll
from customer_order_products
group by customer_id, id_name_coll_type;
```

But when I tried to run the view query then I got the error `ORA-00904: "ID_NAME_COLL_TYPE": invalid identifier`  Then I narrow down the query and just run the following query. Just run select and remove the name from group by.

```
select
    customer_id, 
    max(customer_name) as customer_name, 
    cast(
        collect(
            id_name_type(product_id, product_name)
            order by product_id
        ) as id_name_coll_type
    ) as product_coll
from customer_order_products
group by customer_id;
```

The above query gives the following results

[image: result]

So what is wrong with the `group by customer_id, id_name_coll_type;`? Why in this case I am getting  `"ID_NAME_COLL_TYPE": invalid identifier`. As it is a book example that's why I thought it should work as it is ?  How view will create ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id_name_coll_type` is an identifier for a data type and not an identifier for a column; you must aggregate by columns.

> As it is a book example that's why I thought it should work as it is?

Books can contain mistakes; you should check to see if there is an errata for the book that may contain a correction or if you have the latest version of the book. If not, you can e-mail the author/publisher and let them know of the mistake.

> How view will create?

Do exactly what you did and do not include the `id_name_coll_type` identifier in the `GROUP BY` clause. You do not need to add the collection to the `GROUP BY` clause as `COLLECT` is an aggregation function.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0f09ff5e774dd531eba97c64de1b535d)*

Comment: @MTO I tried `group by customer_id, product_coll;` But still getting `ORA-00904: "PRODUCT_COLL": invalid identifier`. PRODUCT_COLL is the colums that I am getting in the result of SQL query.

Comment: @Basit Just `GROUP BY customer_id` as you did in the second query. If that is not giving the "correct" results then you need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70053769/edit) your question to explain what the "correct" results should be.

Comment: @MTO hhmm ok. Actually I thought may be removing `id_name_coll_type` from `group  by` will cause incorrect result when I will try get the result from this view. That's why I asked. Still learning oracle. But looks like it's a mistake in the book. Anyways thank you. You are very helpful.  Thanks.